# In Win 7 how can i find a file by searching the contents, specifically Open Office Calc

Tags: windows-7

What I want to do is search all folders for a file containing "TEXT" say. All files to be checked, including non- microsoft formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try Wingrep utility. It is free. Doesn't time-expire. At the moment 2.3 is the lat version. http://www.wingrep.com/download.htm